# how to sort nested dictionary python?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

i have the following nested dictionary:

```
{'switch3': {'ip': '192.160.1.2', 'hostname': 'test-1'}, 
'switch2': {'ip': '192.160.1.8', 'hostname': 'test-1'}, 
'switch4': {'ip': '192.160.1.3', 'hostname': 'test-1'}, 
'switch1': {'ip': '192.160.1.4', 'hostname': 'test-1'}}
```

and i want to sort by switch, and get this :

```
{'switch1': {'ip': '192.160.1.4', 'hostname': 'test-1'} 
'switch2': {'ip': '192.160.1.8', 'hostname': 'test-1'}, 
'switch3': {'ip': '192.160.1.2', 'hostname': 'test-1'},
'switch4': {'ip': '192.160.1.3', 'hostname': 'test-1'}}
```

is this possible ?

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered, so you cannot **sort** dictionaries. You can convert them into a (sorted) list...

Comment: Dictionaries are not ordered (prior to CPython 3.6), apply `sorted()` then pass to `OrderedDict`

Comment: `OrderedDict` is still the correct collection in Python 3.6; don’t rely on implementation.

Comment: could you gime an example ?

Comment: Why do you want to sort it? Just to print it in a nice order, or for some other reason?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I sort a dictionary by key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-can-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key)

Comment: thanks, the post also works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that dicts in python are unordered list, You can use the OrderedDict that remember the order of the items.

The following code does seem to sort the dict (only for print), but it's not actually sort it, you should use OrderedDict.

```
mydict = {'switch3': {'ip': '192.160.1.2', 'hostname': 'test-1'}, 
'switch2': {'ip': '192.160.1.8', 'hostname': 'test-1'}, 
'switch4': {'ip': '192.160.1.3', 'hostname': 'test-1'}, 
'switch1': {'ip': '192.160.1.4', 'hostname': 'test-1'}}

sorted_x = sorted(mydict.items())
```

Comment: Nice; `key=lambda p: p[0]` is shorter and about as descriptive, though.

Comment: @Ryan `operator.itemgetter` is faster. Anyway, neither is needed here, `sorted()` without a key works! See the duplicate

Comment: @Ryan , well.. it is shorter ;)

Comment: @Chris_Rands , I've read the duplicate link, it does seem that you're right, fixed it. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: @omri_saadon Given it's a duplicate, just mark it as one, and move on